# Cannot upload document from 19gb with extension .DFSU

Tags: file-upload

I am using sp2010. I try to upload a file which is 19gb in a document library. The extension of this file is .DFSU. I see no error. I still see the popup where you can browse the file after I press on the OK button. Whats the issue. Is the file to large or is the extension not OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

19GB is way way over the default upload size limit. Even if you increase the limit the supported max file size is 2GB.

More, and source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2012/11/16/issues-with-uploading-large-documents-on-document-library-wss-3-0-amp-moss-2007.aspx and http://yalla.itgroove.net/2013/01/sharepoint-2010-file-size-upload-limits-the-essential-mix/